# Generate random numbers with rbinom but exclude 0s from the range

Tags: r, random

I need to generate random numbers with `rbinom` but I need to exclude 0 within the range.

How can I do it?

I would like something similar to:

```
k <- seq(1, 6, by = 1)

binom_pdf = dbinom(k, 322, 0.1, log = FALSE)
```

but I need to get all the relative dataset, because if I do the following:

```
binom_ran = rbinom(100, 322, 0.1)
```

I get values from 0 to 100.

Is there any way I can get around this?

Thanks

Comment: The probability of getting a 0 will dependn on your second and third parameters. Do you need fixed parameters for the simulation?

Comment: yes unfortunately...

Comment: the thing is that if we only know the number of observations used to generate binom_pdf we could just multiply the density values by it

Comment: You could do a hit and miss approach. Just use `rbinom` but throw away the zeros.

Comment: noooo! it will destroy the distribution shape!

Comment: The hit and miss approach guarantees the correct conditional distribution. Your requirement *is* one which changes the shape of the distribution. Depending on what you are trying to do, you could just add 1 ( to one with n = 99) to shift it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let`s suppose that we have the fixed parameters:

- **n**: number of generated values
- **s**: the size of the experiment
- **p**: the probability of a success

  ```
   # Generate initial values
     U<-rbinom(n,s,p)
     # Number and ubication of zero values
       k<-sum(U==0)
       which.k<-which(U==0)

   # While there is still a zero, . . . generate new numbers
     while(k!=0){
       U[which.k]<-rbinom(k,s,p)
         k<-sum(U==0)
         which.k<-which(U==0)
       # Print how many zeroes are still there
         print(k)
   }

  # Print U (without zeroes)
    U
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the hit and miss approach, if you want to sample from the conditional distribution of a binomial given that the number of successes is at least one, you can compute the conditional distribution then directly sample from it.

It is easy to work out that if `X` is binomial with parameters `p` and `n`, then

```
P(X = x | X > 0) = P(X = x)/(1-p)
```

Hence the following function will work:

```
rcond.binom <- function(k,n,p){
  probs <- dbinom(1:n,n,p)/(1-p)
  sample(1:n,k,replace = TRUE,prob = probs)
}
```

If you are going to call the above function numerous times with the same `n` and `p` then you can just precompute the vector `probs` and simply use the last line of the function whenever you need it.

I haven't benchmarked it, but I suspect that the hit-and-miss approach is preferable when `k` is small, `p` not too close to 0, and `n` large, but for larger `k` larger, `p` closer to 0, and `n` smaller then the above might be preferable.